# C# Update Application Based on Updates in DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm creating a chatting application in C# where clients can chat privately, however I’m struggling to update the messages based on changes within the DB (sql-server).

Should I create a constant running thread which requests data after the last message id outputted? I think this may be inefficient, is there other methods? Or could you recommend a better method?

```
   public void Display_Messages(dynamic listbox, int conversation_id)
{
    Connection _connection = new Connection();
    _connection.conn.Open();
    string sql = "SELECT userId, text, messageId FROM message WHERE conversationId =" + conversation_id + ";";  // Update Later to use PS
    dynamic command = new SqlCommand(sql, _connection.conn);
    dynamic data_reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (data_reader.Read())
    {
        listbox.Items.Add(data_reader.GetValue(0) +":"+data_reader.GetValue(1));
    }
    data_reader.Close(); command.Dispose(); _connection.conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: So you are asking if you should be using polling or some form of push notification?

Comment: Please start parametrising your queries!

Comment: Your code is exposed to SQL injection vulnerabilities/problems. Fix that _now_. It looks like you have a "fix this later" comment in there to do so. "Fix laters" _almost never_ happen. Make parameterized queries a habit and do it right the first time, every time.

Comment: @Christopher, Yes Exactly. Is polling a good method for doing this? As the application will need to constantly be checking.

Comment: No, polling is bad for a chat application. So are direct SQL Queries. And unguarded (missing try/finally or using) Disposes. If you are not using a Chat Server along with your DB, then consider sending UDP triggers to the other chat members.

Comment: @Fildor do you know of a good method?

Comment: Well, most chat apps have an actual Server, which will deal with DB access, persisting chats and managing clients. The alternative would be to create some sort of "mesh" of peer-to-peer nodes, that write to the same DB and trigger reads for example through UDP. But even in the latter model, I'd really recommend abstracting DB Access away from UI.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Server's `broker service` which notifies your custom data changes, but there must not be too many listeners on it for performance considerations. The polling mechanisms usually are not efficient enough and put a constant load on the system even when there is no new data to be notified.
You can find all the information you need to use the `broker service` online.

Comment: What about a mixed approach? The Chat API the clients talk to polls regulary - on a acceptable repetiton, to then send out push notificaitons to clients or answers client polling from the cache?